# DocumentViewController for dropbox or google drive

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, dropbox, uidocumentpickervc

In my app i want to access document of Google Drive and Dropbox. For iCloud their is `UIDocumentPickerViewController` which shows file of iCloud.I am looking for something same for Google Drive and Dropbox. Is I have to create `UIDocumentPickerViewController` manually for Dropbox and Google Drive.

I have added this in `UIDocumentMenuViewController`

```
attachmentMenu.addOptionWithTitle("Google Drive", image: R.image.google_Drive(), order: .First, handler: { () -> Void in
      print("Google Drive")

    })
```

I don't know what to do in handler.

Answer (score 1):

UIDocumentPickerViewController can pick documents also from Google Drive and Dropbox app if they are installed on the device

Comment: thanks...i got what i wanted.i need to use set the UTI.